# Camera Access Failure after Migration to Android 14

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-manifest, android-14

I have recently migrated my Java 11 Android application from Android 13 to Android 14. As part of this migration, I updated the compileSDK and targetSDK versions to 34. Following the migration guide provided by Android, I made necessary adjustments as recommended. However, after the migration, my application is encountering an issue where it is unable to access the device camera.

Upon clicking a button designated to capture a photo, the button remains clickable, but there is no access granted to the camera. This functionality was working fine before the migration.

I reviewed the Android documentation regarding the migration to Android 14 and did not find any explicit changes related to camera access permissions or functionality.

I am seeking assistance in identifying any potential changes or updates in Android 14 that might affect camera access permissions or functionality. Additionally, any guidance or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your attention to this matter.

I attempted to modify the permissions within the AndroidManifest.xml file. Specifically, I ensured that the necessary camera permissions were correctly declared and configured according to Android's documentation.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code parts that now fail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.